# Should both root and wheel users own the files that originally were only owned by root?

Tags: file-permissions, root, chmod

Should a wheel user that was created to disable root login and secure SSH have the same ownership as root from a security point of view?

Answer (score 2):

No.

Modern Unix systems use user groups to control access privileges. The `wheel` group is a special user group used on some Unix systems to control access to the `su` **command, which allows a user to masquerade as another user (usually the super user).**

Comment: Uhm… on Berkeley Unix, `wheel` is just gid 0, but there’s no corresponding uid (well there is, it’s just `root`). This answer is wrong, but the question itself is… I’d say bad. I don’t get what he wants to ask.

Comment: @mirabilos I think the OP is asking about Linux. AFAIK most Linux distros have a `root` group with GID 0, and a separate `wheel` (or sometimes `sudo`) group that controls access to `sudo`.

Comment: Ah, I know of that as `sudo` group (on BSD, the `wheel` group indeed does both `su` and `sudo`). Thanks for clearing up.